# Validation in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id="form1" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Test</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="text" name="field1" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and the following js script:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $.validator.addMethod('integer', function (value, element, param) {
                return (value != 0) && (value == parseInt(value, 10));
            }, 'Please enter a non zero integer value!');


            $("#form1").validate({
                    field1: {
                        required: true,
                        integer: true
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

FirstName validation works, field1 validation - does not work. If I remove this part from page:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

then field1 validation works. So, "standard" validation conflicts with my validation. How to combine it?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a `unobtrusive.adapter` to jquery validate and include an associated `data-val-` attribute to the control, add add `ValidationMessageFor()` to display the message

Add the following scripts

```
// function to test for integer and not equal to zero
function isInteger(value) {
  return (value != 0) && (value == parseInt(value, 10));
}

$.validator.addMethod('integer', function (value, element, params) {
  return isInteger(value);
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("integer", [], function (options) {
  options.rules['integer'] = {};
  options.messages['integer'] = options.message;
});
```

And in the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YourInteger, new { data_val_integer = "The field must be an integer and not equal to zero" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.YourInteger)
```

To avoid adding the `data_val_integer` manually, you could create a custom helper, for example

```
public static MvcHtmlString IntegerFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
  string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
  string message = string.Format("The field {0} must be an integer and not equal to zero", name);
  return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(helper, expression, new { htmlAttributes = new { data_val_integer = message }})
}
```

and then in the view

```
@Html.IntegerFor(m => m.YourInteger)
```

Comment: thank you, but it does not work. Maybe need to add validate method?

Comment: It does work, I have already tested it (as have others). I can only assume you have other scripts interfering (or have not deleted the scripts you posted in the question)

Comment: look at this http://jsfiddle.net/2VJZT/487/ . What is incorrect (copy of result html)?

Comment: No validation is being fired at all (even on the "FirstName" control which has a required attribute) so its got nothing to do with the code in my answer. You also have another file named `additional-method.js` which also has an integer validation -  `jQuery.validator.addMethod("integer", function(value, element) { return this.optional(element) || /^-?\d+$/.test(value); }, "A positive or negative non-decimal number please");` which would have done the validation anyway (I haven't tested that one but it looks OK)

Comment: Also if you check the console, you will see 2 errors - `Unexpected token <` and `Cannot read property 'adapters' of undefined`

Comment: strange, FirstName is works for me, I see "The FirstName field is required. " by that link. And I don't have such errors in console. http://www.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/BKloRdRAmU0.html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2VJZT/488/ - renamed 'integer' to 'integer2'. The same, FirstName validation works,  TheSameString does not... Seems, this model of validation is difficult for me :(

Comment: I still get both those errors with the second fiddle (and no validation for FirstName) - using Chrome. All I can suggest is you create a new model (with one `int` property) and view for testing and include just the jquery, jquery-validate and jquery-validate-unobtrusive files followed by the scripts in my answer